# Collecting/uploading file as custom attribute during the sign up process in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need to collect image/file during the registration process of a new user belonging to my Azure AD B2C teanant instance.
Currently image/file upload is [not supported](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39187#issuecomment-534414397) as custom attribute.

I'm considering to leverage on the "UX customization" feature supported by Azure AD B2C to accomplish my need. These are the steps I'm planning to implement:

1. Define custom attribute (type=string) to store the file url
2. [Create a Page layout template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) for the "local account sign up page"
3. Hide [via javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) (injected into the custom html page) the input field created by Azure AD B2C for the custom attribute described at step 1
4. Add [via javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) a [form/input type=file to collect](https://html.com/input-type-file/) and store via ajax the uploaded file. The input field will be placed just after the input field created by Azure AD B2C for the custom attribute described at step 1
5. Fill the custom attribute input field with the asset url returned by the ajax call at step 4
6. Post the form using the Azure AD B2C submit button
7. Be able to retrieve via Azure AD Graph API user attributes including the custom attribute containing the asset url. I'll take care to protect the asset url from public requests.

I'm aware of the javascript restrictions using custom page layout as describe within the documentation page but they are not seem to prevent my goal.

Do you think this approach is feasible or am I missing something?
Is there any Azure AD B2C internal restriction that prevents my scenario to succeed?

Comment: Are you using Custom policies to Built-in user flows?

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal currently I'm using user flows and I'd like to stick w/ those for the sake of simplicity but I'm open to switch if needed